# Triple integral question- two balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

How can I calculate the volume bounded between the two surfaces:
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=1, \quad x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1
$$
and contains the point $(0,0.5,0)$.

When I move to spherical coordinates, I obtain obviously that $r\leq 1$. But, how can I determine the rest of the constraints on my variables $r,\theta,\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set
\begin{align}
 & x=r \cos \theta \\ 
 & z=r\sin \theta \\ 
\end{align}
we have 
$$\left| \frac{\partial (x,z)}{\partial (r ,\theta )} \right|dr d\theta=r\,dr d \,\theta=dzdx $$
since the region of Integration contains $(0,0.5,0)$, thus
$$\quad x^2+y^2+z^2=1\implies y=\sqrt{1-r^2}$$
$$ x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1\implies y=1-\sqrt{1-r^2}$$
therefore
$$V=\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\int_{0}^{1}{\int_{1-\sqrt{1-{{r}^{2}}}}^{\sqrt{1-{{r}^{2}}}}{\,\,dydrd\theta }}}$$